# retrieving posted files using Golang Gin

Tags: file-upload, go

I'm using the Golang framework Gin for a while now with no issues but I now need to process images posted to my API.

I can probably figure out how to deal with validating, resizing and storing the image but for now I'm just struggling to figure out how to grab the posted file and assign it to a variable.

I've looked at the Gin API docs but nothing is jumping out at me.

I'm curling my API as follows (this might be wrong?)...

```
$ time curl -X POST --form upload=@ss.png -H "Content-Type: application/json"  --cookie 'session=23423v243v25c08efb5805a09b5f288329003' "http://127.0.0.1:8080/v1.0/icon" --form data='{"json_name":"test json name","title":"Test","url":"http://sometest.com"}'
```

Comment: I wanted to clarify in the above curl you want to assign the png to a variable or post body content ?

Comment: @KunalJha I want to retrieve an image (and manipulate it) which has been POSTed to my API. The above curl is just my stab at POSTing an image.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I will try to just answer the retrieving the filename and assigning it to the variable, because handling the json part is already taken care by @AlexAtNet.
Let me know if this works for you

```
    func (c *gin.Context) {

        file, header , err := c.Request.FormFile("upload")
        filename := header.Filename
        fmt.Println(header.Filename)
        out, err := os.Create("./tmp/"+filename+".png")
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        defer out.Close()
        _, err = io.Copy(out, file)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }   
    }
```

Comment: Many thanks Kunal, I just needed to change my header type to  -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data"

Comment: Do you have any snippet for multiple files ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to get the HTTP request from the gin.Context and read from its Body property:

```
func(c *gin.Context) {
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(c.Request.Body)
    var t struct {
      Name string `json:"json_name"`
      Title string `json:"title"`
      Url string `json:"url"`
    }
    err := decoder.Decode(&t)
    if err != nil {
        panic()
    }
    log.Println(t)
}
```